# Jquery dialog height and vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dialog

I am returning data via ajax to populate a jquery dialog. The ajax is basically an html table with a variable amount of rows.

I'd like the dialog to expand to show the rows, up to a certain vertical size (350px), at which point it should show a vertical scrollbar.

So, this seems to work fine - the dialog resizes correctly depending on the number of rows. But, I never get the vertical scrollbar - so if I have 20 rows, then I only get to see the last 9.

How do I force the vertical scrollbar if the height would have been more than 350px?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myurl',
    data: postdata,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.success && result.data) {
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html(result.data).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'History',
                modal: true,
                height: Math.min((result.rows * 25) + 150, 350),
                width: 800
            });
            $dialog.dialog('open');

        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should add css property `overflow:auto` for content div.

```
$("<div></div>").css({height:"350px", overflow:"auto"});
```

If you need ONLY vertical scroll `overflow-y:auto` and `overflow-x:hidden`

Comment: OK, that works, but why is the scrollbar scrolled down to the bottom of the dialog content, and not at the top?

Comment: Sorry, I've improved my example and added jquery ui dialog. http://jsfiddle.net/D3ERm/  (In this example result.rows = 20)

Comment: Setting the css AFTER the call to dialog() did the trick for me: `$("<div></div>").dialog({...}).css({height:"350px", overflow:"auto"})`

Answer (score 4):

use css max-height: 350px; and overflow:auto; .. should be fine

Answer (score 3):

I know this is kind of old but none of these worked for me. Here is what is working as of jQuery UI 1.10.

```
 $("#helptext").dialog({
        title: 'Blog Help',
        autoOpen: false,
        width: '90%',
        height: ($(window).height() - 200),
        modal: true
  });
```

Adjust Height and width as you like. I have allot of text in my dialog and didn't want to scroll the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to give a fixed px height so I found a solution giving the model the following css rules.

```
.modal {
  display: inline-block !important;
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;/* Or scroll, depending on your needs*/}
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked:

```
    .jconfirm-holder { 
       overflow-y: auto; 
   }
```